# Access current entity in custom symfony2 constraint validator

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to access the entity of the property currently being validated in a custom constraint validator, and if so, how? As far as i can see, I only have access to the value (and any services I might choose to inject, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in need for that too.
Please find below a full example :

The entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity\MarketPlace;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use AppBundle\Model\BaseCategoryClass as BaseCategory;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as FMUAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MarketPlace\ProductRepository")
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @FMUAssert\UnitConstraint()
 */
class Product extends BaseCategory
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

The constraint:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UnitConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'La chaîne "%string%" contient un caractère non autorisé : elle ne peut contenir que des lettres et des chiffres.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'unit_validator';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

The constraint Validator:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class UnitConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        exit(var_dump(get_class($entity)));
        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
    }
}
```

And the declaration as a service:

```
services:
    unit_validator:
        class: %unit_validator.class%
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: unit_validator }
```

The exit vardump I've put does get me the entity class name, it's working!

Comment: Great! Just one little remark: you could also use `dump` instead of `var_dump`. It shows the output very nicely formatted and styled.

Answer (score 10):

In case if you have property validator, you can also access validated object in Validator through ExecutionContext:

http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Validator/Context/ExecutionContextInterface.html#method_getObject

```
class SomeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $object = $this->context->getObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns null. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a way. [Class constraint validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) has an entire entity in scope.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation was somewhat unclear so I didn't quote catch that.

Comment: @EirikA.Johansen, could you please provide an example? I am trying to do the same thing as described in the Symfony example but without success. A more detaild example will be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Ey, well it depends on how are you validating the entity. For example, I'm validating my entity through a Form so, to get the entity in the ConstraintValidator I just need to get de context root and get the data from my form:

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ValidDnieValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {

        $user = $this->context->getRoot()->getData();
```